# What causes Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech Recognizer objects to send SessionStopped events?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, speech

What causes a Speech Recognizer Session to end? For reference, here is my code:

```
        Stream sos = new MemoryStream();
        byte channels = 1;
        byte bitsPerSample = 16;
        uint samplesPerSecond = 16000;
        var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(samplesPerSecond, bitsPerSample, channels);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePullStream(new BinaryAudioStreamReader(sos), audioFormat);
        var t = Task.Run(() => SpeechRecognitionSamples.RecognitionWithBufferStreamAsync(audioInputStream));
```

The log prints this:

Session started event.

Read: size: 3200

Read: databuffer.Length: 3200

The thread 0x19850 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Session stopped event.

When I point the DataAvailable writer to a file, it writes successfully. What are things that trigger a recognizer session to end?

This event doesn't send a reason code like the Cancelled event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Continuous mode, the only way the session ends is when you hit the end of the file (return 0 for the amount of data written), or call Stop.

If you are in RecognizeOnce mode,  the session ends after the first phrase is recognized (when there is enough silence) or when you hit the end of the file, whichever comes first.